# dependency injection based on user input

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Consider the code snippet (I used the strategy Pattern in the example) :
[image]

```
    abstract class SortStrategy
        {
           public abstract void Sort(ArrayList list);
        }
  class QuickSort : SortStrategy
    {
        public override void Sort(ArrayList list)
            {
             //...
            }
    }
  class ShellSort : SortStrategy
    {
         public override void Sort(ArrayList list)
              {
               // ....
              }
    }
```

and in Context :

```
 class SortedList
  {
    private ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    private SortStrategy sortstrategy;

    public void SetSortStrategy(SortStrategy sortstrategy)
    {
        this.sortstrategy = sortstrategy;
    }
    public void Add(string name)
    {
        list.Add(name);
    }
    public void Sort()
    {
        sortstrategy.Sort(list);
    }
}
```

My question is that the end user through the UI and by selecting an option says to use the method for example QuickSort to sort, but what should I do, how to set SetSortStrategy (or how to  dependency injection in this case)

Comment: `SortedList.SetSortStrategy(new ConcreteStratagy())` ?

Comment: @GuruStron : I am looking for ConcreteStratagy to be set by the user! Is it possible?

Comment: Please define "user".

Comment: How do user choose the strategy? your code should initialized object of appropriate strategy and pass to `SetSortStrategy` based on the user choice..

Comment: @GuruStron : I mean, for example, the end user says through the UI to use the ShellSort or QuickSort method

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya : Can you give me an example of how to do it?

Comment: `SortStrategy` isn't a dependency in your code; it is set via a method, so why not just use `new`?

Comment: @farshid I think answer from FindOutIslamNow should help you solve the issue.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya : In order to observe the principle of open / close (SOLID) I do not want to use switch Case. My problem starts here

Comment: You can use DI to first register all the types of Strategies and then resolved from it by passing the value selected by the user... are you using any DI framework?

Comment: Having a factory class to get the needed type without worrying about how they are instantiated, is not violation of open/close principle. It is one of 24 GOF patterns and it used for such kind of uses.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya : Thanks if you can help me further with an example

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya : What do you think of Toxantron's response?

Comment: @farshid I am not sure how that works... but if that solves your problem then that's the solution...  it is using some form of DI to resolve the types at runtime based on some value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using factory pattern with dependency injection:

```
public enum StrategyType
{
   A,
   B,
   C
}

public interface IStrategyFactory {
   IStrategy Create();
}

public class BasedOnUserSelStrategyFactory {

   public IStrategy Create() {
     StrategyType type = ReadUserSelectionFromFile(); // or any place stored

     switch (type) {
       case StrategyType.A:
          return di.Resolve<AStrategy>(); // resolve using di container
       case StrategyType.B:
          return di.Resolve<BStrategy>(); // resolve using di container
       case StrategyType.C:
          return di.Resolve<CStrategy>(); // resolve using di container
       default:
          throw new ArgumentException("type");
     }
   }
}
```

Then, register factory in di:

```
di.Register<IStrategyFactory>().As<BasedOnUserSelStrategyFactory>();
```

Finally:

```
IStrategy s = di.Resolve<IStrategyFactory>().Create();
s.MyOperation();
```

Comment: In order to observe the principle of open / close
 (SOLID) I do not want to use switch Case. My problem starts here

Answer (score 0):

The Castle.Windsor based DI of our [MORYX-Framework](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Platform) allows users to configure a `ModuleStrategy` property in the config.

When a modules config looks like this:

```cs
public class ModuleConfig : ConfigBase
{
    [DataMember, PluginStrategy(typeof(SortStrategy))]
    [ModuleStrategy(typeof(SortStrategy))]
    public string SortStrategy { get; set; }
}
```

The user can choose one of the found classes and every import of `SortStragy` is automatically filled with an instance. Using the graphic interface the user can select `QuickSort` and `ShellSort`, as well as any other implementation found at runtime from a drop-down box.

```cs
[Plugin(LifeCycle.Transient, typeof(SortStrategy))]
class QuickSort : SortStrategy
{
  // ...
}

class SortedList
{
    private ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    // injected with either QuickSort or ShellSort
    public SortStrategy Sortstrategy { get; set; }

    public void Add(string name)
    {
        list.Add(name);
    }
    public void Sort()
    {
        sortstrategy.Sort(list);
    }
}
```

If you prefer to use the factory pattern, you can also declare a named factory. This can create any strategy registered as shown above.

```cs
[PluginFactory(typeof(INameBasedComponentSelector))]
public interface ISortStrategyFactory
{
    SortStrategy Create(string name);

    void Destroy(SortStrategy instance);
}
```

If you use Castle.Windsor, this is the code (Licensed under Apache2.0) we use to configure the override on all dependency declarations:
https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Platform/blob/dev/src/Moryx.Container/LocalContainer/LocalRegistrator.cs#L34

Comment: how to use ModuleConfig ?

Comment: If you use MORYX, the config is part of your Module and accessible through the applications web configuration. This approach works if you want to configure the strategy per lifecycle, not per request. When selecting per request, you will need the factory - either ours or the basic factory pattern.

Comment: how to use Castle.Windsor in mvc core?